# does Spring WebClient support Multiparts/related?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

am trying to create webcleint to send a multipart/related type content but spring keeps changing the content type. I created a project to receive my request and check the received request and headers generated from the web client and however, the request is generated successfully and I found the correct value of another header like accept is received as multipart/related. but spring keeps changing the content type from multipart/related to multipart/formData.

```
 webClient.post()
          .uri(endpoint)
          .accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_RELATED)
          .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_RELATED)
          .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(createMultiparts()))
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(String.class)
          .subscribe();
```

createmultiparts method :

```
        public MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> createMultiparts() throws IOException {

        File attachment = new File("src/main/resources/attachment.xml");
        File request = new File("src/main/resources/request.xml");
        MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        builder.part("body", new String(Files.readAllBytes(request.toPath())))
                .header("Content-Type", "Multipart/related; charset=UTF-8; type=\"text/xml\"")
                .header("Content-Disposition", "");
        builder.part("file", new String(Files.readAllBytes(attachment.toPath())))
                .header("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; name=\"811_Bill_Attachment.xml\"; filename=\"811_Bill_Attachment.xml\"")
                .header("Content-ID", "1068118164010");
        return builder.build();
    }
```

is there is any way that I intercept the request before sending it to change the content type or any solution to this issue ?

below is the printed logs at the receiver :

```
        log.info("recieved request {}", httpRequest.getContentType());
        log.info("recieved header {}", httpRequest.getHeader("Content-Type"));
        log.info("recieved accept {}", httpRequest.getHeader("accept"));
        log.info("recieved body {}", new String(httpRequest.getCachedBody()));

logs : recieved request multipart/form-data;boundary=CRsAqXiWZRxzTBwyr4yd7mu5JQhla_
2021-12-11 21:08:09.705  INFO 23592 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.e.demo.controller.ServerController     : recieved header multipart/form-data;boundary=CRsAqXiWZRxzTBwyr4yd7mu5JQhla_
2021-12-11 21:08:09.705  INFO 23592 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.e.demo.controller.ServerController     : recieved accept multipart/related
```

Comment: yes they support it, but you cant use `fromMultipartData` since what you are sending is not `form-data` have you tried https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/MultipartBodyBuilder.html

Comment: am already using it in creating the multi parts I have added the code in the question, is there is another way that I can pass the multi parts to the body without using the fromMultipartData  ?

Answer (score 4):

Like Mohamed said, you need to set the bodyValue manually. Here is how to create the multi parts.

Note, below example uses a byte array resource, but you can use any instance of org.springframework.core.io.Resource.

```
// used imports:
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.MultipartBodyBuilder;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

    private MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> createMultiPartRelatedBody(YourRequestType request, byte[] content) {
        var multipartBodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        var filePart = new ByteArrayResource(content); // resource type matters for file type!
        multipartBodyBuilder
            .part("part 1 with json", request, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("foo", "bar");
        multipartBodyBuilder
            .part("part 2 with file content", filePart)
            .filename(request.getFileName()) // Only needed if resource type does not expose filename (ByteArrayResource doesn't)
            .header("foo", "bar");
        return multipartBodyBuilder.build();
    }
```

So, do NOT use something like:

```
.body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
```

Because the multipartInserter extends FormInserter and will cause the form-data content-type to be used. Instead, just set the content type and body manually:

```
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_RELATED)
        .bodyValue(createMultiPartRelatedBody(request))
```

Comment: Hmm `MULTIPART_RELATED` is from Spring `5.2.5` and `bodyValue` is from `Spring 5.2` I have older Spring - 5.0.8 and have to think how to do this the other way.

Comment: Your are a savior - i wonder why this is not marked as "Accepted Answer" - i just invoked SOAP Attachements with this. The whole stack of SOAP framework  is out of the world experience :D

Comment: `filename` saved my day